# Errors trying to build Cordova Window app

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have a cordova application that runs fine on android, iOS and wp8.  Now we would like it to run on windows.  I have added the platform using the following command

```
cordova platform add windows
```

This adds all the plugins for me, now i build the project using

```
cordova build windows
```

For some reason my plugins and other basic features are not working.  For example, i have the following cordova plugins installed

```
cordova plugin list
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.10
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.6
```

I havent tried camera yet, but upon my application starting, i try to hide the splash screen and status bar, and i get these errors

> Exception was thrown at line 96, column 9 in
>   ms-appx://MY.APP.ID/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.statusbar/src/windows/StatusBarProxy.js
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'hideAsync' of undefined or null reference

and

> Exception was thrown at line 82, column 9 in
>   ms-appx://MY.APP.ID/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen/www/windows8/SplashScreenProxy.js
>   0x80004002 - JavaScript runtime error: No such interface supported

I have even tried to show a console.log, which never shows anymore?  I know in WP8 projects you have to change the DEFINE DEBUG flag, but i cannot find this on the new windows project.

To get round console, i thought i would try and show an alert, which you can do with

```
(new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Content", "Title")).showAsync().done();
```

But i get an error message of

> Exception was thrown at line 47, column 9 in
>   ms-appx://com.measure2improve.m2ianywhere/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/src/windows/NotificationProxy.js
>
> 0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.

I am obviously missing something here, if someone could let me know what i have missed, would be very much appriecated.